# Logging Library for .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: logging, compact-framework, log4net, nlog

Any good logging libraries that support .NET compact framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

log4net is a good choice, I use it for all projects.

Comment: Have you tried it on Compact Framework... I see it is supported! Tnx!!!

Answer (score 1):

Nlog does too.
There are some functionalities not available in compact network (logging of Exception instances out of the box for example).

Answer (score 0):

log4net actually supports compact framework 1.0, will try it out!

Read more [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html)

Answer (score 0):

[NLog](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=116456&package_id=128559) also supports .NET Compact Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Log4net is the best option, but it doesn't have Zip log feature.